# Asterisk AGI Python Script completed, returning 0

Tags: python, asterisk, raspberry-pi3, agi

I used online tutorial to run an Python script in asterisk using AGI. But it returns,

```
AGI Script easy.py completed, returning 0
```

So I enabled debug mode and got an output.

AGI Debugging Enabled

```
== Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184  
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5    
-- Executing [0112617769@from-trunk:1] Answer("SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b", "") 
in new stack  
-- Executing [0112617769@from-trunk:2] AGI("SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b", "easy.py") in new stack    
-- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/easy.py
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_request: easy.py
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_channel: SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_language: en
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_type: SIP
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_uniqueid: 1503228907.11
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_version: 13.15.0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_callerid: 0713029474
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_calleridname: unknown
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_callingpres: 0 
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_callingani2: 0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_callington: 0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_callingtns: 0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_dnid: 0112617769
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_rdnis: unknown
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_context: from-trunk
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_extension: 0112617769
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_priority: 2
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_enhanced: 0.0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_accountcode: 
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >> agi_threadid: 1956721696
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Tx >>    
-- <SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b>AGI Script easy.py completed, returning 0    
-- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b' status is 'UNKNOWN'   
-- Executing [h@from-trunk:1] Answer("SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b", "") in new stack  
== Spawn extension (from-trunk, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000b'  
== Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184 
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5    
-- Executing [0112617769@from-trunk:1] Answer("SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c", "") 
in new stack   
-- Executing [0112617769@from-trunk:2] AGI("SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c", "easy.py") in new stack    
-- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/easy.py
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_request: easy.py
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_channel: SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_language: en
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_type: SIP
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_uniqueid: 1503228913.12
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_version: 13.15.0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_callerid: OBITRUNK1
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_calleridname: unknown
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_callingpres: 0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_callingani2: 0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_callington: 0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_callingtns: 0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_dnid: 0112617769
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_rdnis: unknown
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_context: from-trunk
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_extension: 0112617769
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_priority: 2
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_enhanced: 0.0
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_accountcode: 
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >> agi_threadid: 1980019744
<SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Tx >>     
-- <SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c>AGI Script easy.py completed, returning 0  
-- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c' status is 'UNKNOWN'    

-- Executing [h@from-trunk:1] Answer("SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c", "") in new stack
== Spawn extension (from-trunk, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/OBITRUNK1-0000000c'  
== Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
```

Above code is what I got when I receive a call. Also there are three problems I want to solve.

**Problems**

1) This shows

```
AGI Script easy.py completed, returning 0
```

And I don't know why. As a online forum suggested, I even changed the easy.py location to /var/test/easy.py but it didn't work. So I wanna solve this since it does not give what I expect.

This is easy.py code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from asterisk.agi import *

agi = AGI()
agi.verbose("python agi started")
callerId = agi.env['agi_callerid']
agi.verbose("call from %s" % callerId)
while True:
  agi.stream_file('vm-extension')
  result = agi.wait_for_digit(-1)
  agi.verbose("got digit %s" % result)
  if result.isdigit():
    agi.say_number(result)
  else:
   agi.verbose("bye!")
   agi.hangup()
   sys.exit()
```

2) When the phone rings, you can see easy.py has executed two times. (This only shows two times but when it keeps ringing it executes in a loop). I couldn't find a solution for that. Also from second loop, it starts to show callerid as OBITRUNK1.

3) When this code runs, my landline phone stops ringing but when I remove the code from the extensions.conf file and place the standard extensions.conf codes, landline rings like it normally does.

**Note** : I know this is wrong. But since adding extensions to extensions_custom.conf didn't work, I modified extensions.conf file. Actually below is how extensions.conf file looks when AGI works.

extensions.conf

```
from trunk:
[from-trunk]
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
exten => _X.,n,AGI(/var/test/easy.py)
```

Hope someone can help me. I tried to find solutions for them in several web sites and books, but had no luck. Thank you.